# Generate a left hand menu for product categories in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking for a method to generate a left hand menu in Magento much like the top menu present in the default template, anyone have a method for doing this?

Comment: @Hima: You might wanna read the site FAQ once. We don't ans such questions here since they are not programming related. Anyways welcome to stack overflow. Do post any programming related questions if you have.

Comment: Actually, this is borderline programming related, as Magento's layout system uses a simple domain specific language for specifying layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

there are some extensions and wiki entries which should help fulfill your needs. See some possible solutions here (all can be found, if you look for `vertical navigation` in Magento Boards):

[Vertical Navigation with CSS Classes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/763/)

[How to create a vertical left hand menu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu)

M

Comment: I'm using the Vertical Navigation extension in my Magento site and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to muck around with the PHP templates, here is how I've done it using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
<style>
    #left-nav {float:left; width:160px;border:1px solid #000; border-width:1px 1px 0;margin-right:8px;}
    #left-nav li {border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
    #left-nav a {display:block; text-decoration:none; background:#FFF; color:#000; padding:8px;}
    #left-nav a:hover {color:#FFF; background:#000;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('<ul id="left-nav" />')
          .html($("#nav").html())
          .find("li")
          .removeClass("level0")
          .prependTo("#main");
        $(".header-nav-container").hide();
    });
</script>
```